# how to conditionally multiply columns in r

Tags: r, function, data.table, tidyverse, arithmetic-expressions

I would appreciate any help to create a function that conducts pairwise column multiplication in a generalized way.

Given the sample data `sampleDT` below with the variables `dolar.wage_x`, and the `data.table` function to generate the variables `euro.wage_x`, I want a function that:

> creates new variables named `product.wage_x` which contain for each
>   pair  `dollar.wage_x` and `euro.wage_x` the result of the
>   multiplication of `dollar.wage_x` by `euro.wage_x`, where x is the
>   number of pairwise `dollar.wage_x` and `euro.wage_x` variables.

**#sample data**

```
sampleDT<-structure(list(id = 1:10, N = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), A = c(62L, 96L, 17L, 41L, 212L, 143L, 143L, 
    143L, 73L, 73L), B = c(3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 170L, 21L, 0L, 33L, 62L, 
    17L), C = c(0.05, 0.01, 0, 0.05, 0.8, 0.15, 0, 0.23, 0.85, 0.23
    ), employer = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), G = c(1.94, 1.19, 1.16, 
    1.16, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), H = c(0.14, 0.24, 
    0.28, 0.28, 0.21, 0.12, 0.17, 0.07, 0.14, 0.12), dollar.wage_1 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_2 = c(1.93, 
    1.18, 3.15, 3.15, 1.12, 1.12, 2.12, 1.12, 1.11, 1.11), dollar.wage_3 = c(1.95, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13), dollar.wage_4 = c(1.94, 
    1.18, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_5 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_6 = c(1.94, 
    1.18, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_7 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.14, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_8 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_9 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12), dollar.wage_10 = c(1.94, 
    1.19, 3.16, 3.16, 1.13, 1.13, 2.13, 1.13, 1.12, 1.12)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**#function to create the variables `euro.wage_x`**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sampleDT)
o_cols <- grep("^dollar", names(sampleDT), value = TRUE)
n_cols <- sub("^dollar", "euro", o_cols)
sampleDT[, (n_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(j) ifelse(employer == 1, 3 - 5 / j, 2 * j)), .SDcols = o_cols]
```

**#expected output**

```
   id  N  A B    C employer F    G    H dollar.wage_1 dollar.wage_2 dollar.wage_3 dollar.wage_4 dollar.wage_5 dollar.wage_6 dollar.wage_7 dollar.wage_8 dollar.wage_9 dollar.wage_10 euro.wage_1 euro.wage_2 euro.wage_3 euro.wage_4 euro.wage_5 euro.wage_6 euro.wage_7 euro.wage_8 euro.wage_9 euro.wage_10 product.wage_1 product.wage_2 product.wage_3 product.wage_4 product.wage_5 product.wage_6 product.wage_7 product.wage_8 product.wage_9 product.wage_10
1:  1 10 62 3 0.05        1 0 1.94 0.14          1.94          1.93          1.95          1.94          1.94          1.94          1.94          1.94          1.94           1.94   0.4226804   0.4093264   0.4358974   0.4226804   0.4226804   0.4226804   0.4226804   0.4226804   0.4226804    0.4226804       4.5897561       4.7150633       4.4735294       4.5897561       4.5897561       4.5897561       4.5897561       4.5897561       4.5897561        4.5897561
2:  2 10 96 1 0.01        1 0 1.19 0.24          1.19          1.18          1.19          1.18          1.19          1.18          1.19          1.19          1.19           1.19  -1.2016807  -1.2372881  -1.2016807  -1.2372881  -1.2016807  -1.2372881  -1.2016807  -1.2016807  -1.2016807   -1.2016807      -0.9902797      -0.9536986      -0.9902797      -0.9536986      -0.9902797      -0.9536986      -0.9902797      -0.9902797      -0.9902797       -0.9902797
3:  3 10 17 0 0.00        0 0 1.16 0.28          3.16          3.15          3.16          3.16          3.16          3.16          3.16          3.16          3.16           3.16   6.3200000   6.3000000   6.3200000   6.3200000   6.3200000   6.3200000   6.3200000   6.3200000   6.3200000    6.3200000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000       0.5000000        0.5000000
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Yes. Just s second. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell the issue in the last piece of code

Comment: @akrun. Just posted the expected output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  If it is pairwise multipication `sampleDT[,  Map(`*`, .SD[, o_cols, with = FALSE], .SD[, n_cols, with = FALSE])]`

Comment: I get this error: `Error: unexpected '*' in "sampleDT[, Map(*"`

Comment: sorry, I meant within quotes. `"*"`  Used backquotes, which got stripped off while posting

Comment: Yes. It produces the numbers but I would like the function to create new variables named `product.wage_x` which contain for each pair  `dollar.wage_x` and `euro.wage_x` the result of the multiplication of `dollar.wage_x` by `euro.wage_x`, where x is the number of pairwise `dollar.wage_x` and `euro.wage_x` variables. Additionally, keep the variables `dollar.wage_x` and `euro.wage_x` unchanged in the dataframe. Presentation just like the example in the `expected output` above.

Comment: IN that case, just assign it to a new vector of column names just like you created 'o_cols" or 'n_cols'

Comment: Does that solve the issue

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, @akrun. Apologise for taking a long time to give feedback. Yes, I am able to solve the problem using your solution. Great!